# How to resolve HTTP Parameter Pollution warning?

Tags: scala, find-sec-bugs

While checking for `findSpecBugs` warnings in my scala based application, I encountered:

> HTTP Parameter Pollution warning with the message: Concatenating unvalidated user input into a URL can allow an attacker to override the value of a request parameter.

This issue is arising when I am concatenating a URL with a value fetched from the database.
Any idea how can I sanitize or validate that value, or is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Thanks @Joe, this lowered the level of warning to low, but has not removed it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `URIBuilder` and set the `setParameter(<param>, <value>)`. Like the following:

```
val builder = new URIBuilder(<url>)
    builder.setParameter("pparam1", "value1").setParameter("param2", "value2")
val request = new HttpGet(builder.build())
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @himanshuIIITian for your answer. 
This really helped and resolved the warning completely.

Comment: URIBuilder will be used in the solution sample for the next version of FSB.